# Why don't I need a 32 bit key, or initialization vector for NodeJS crypto?

Tags: ruby, node.js

I was working interchangeably with Node's `crypto` library and Ruby's `OpenSSL` library.

The challenge I was coming across was that I could encrypt using`aes256` in both libraries.

However, in node using the [`crypto.createDecipher('aes256', key)`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createdecipher_algorithm_password) I could have a key that was less than 32 bits long, but ruby would throw an error saying the key is not long enough when using:

```
cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new 'aes256'
cipher.encrypt
key = 'geeses'
```

I also don't have to set an initialization vector for node, but ruby seems to set one under the covers. I'm pretty new to this crypto stuff, what's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use [`crypto.createDecipher()`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createdecipher_algorithm_password), the value you pass as the second argument is a password from which a key and IV will be derived (using one iteration of MD5 hashing). This is accomplished by [using](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/a37401e0612578a76e6b148a798868ecbf62d9b7/src/node_crypto.cc#L3144-L3151) [`EVP_BytesToKey()`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/crypto/EVP_BytesToKey.html) to create those two values. OpenSSL knows the correct lengths both values need to be because the cipher is also passed to `EVP_BytesToKey()`.

So most likely the Ruby function is more analogous to node's [`crypto.createDecipheriv()`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createdecipheriv_algorithm_key_iv) which accepts both a key and an IV (which need to be the right lengths for the cipher).

Answer (score 4):

While @mscdex answers is perfectly, I want to add how to get a cipher with a specific key when your algorithm does not require Initialization Vector using the `crypto.createCipheriv` or `crypto.createDecipheriv`

Taking the case of AES-256-ECB where chaining is not done and hence IV is not used.
You can pass empty Buffer as IV.

```
    var data = "plaintext";
    const key = crypto.randomBytes(32);
    var iv = new Buffer('');
    var cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('AES-256-ECB',key,iv);
    var encrypted = cipher.update(data,'utf8','base64');
    encrypted += cipheriv.final('base64');
    console.log('encrypted AES-256-ECB',encrypted);
```

And decrypt fairly simply using the same pattern:

```
   var decipheriv = crypto.createDecipheriv('AES-256-ECB',key,iv);
   var decryptediv = decipheriv.update(encrypted,'base64','utf8');
   decryptediv += decipheriv.final('utf8');
   console.log('decrypted base64 aes-256 ',decryptediv);
```

Comment: As least as of today, the `createDeciperiv` method allows you to pass `null` for the iv parameter when you don't need it.